# generateChangelog ignores diffTypes="data"

Tags: liquibase

I run

```
liquibase generateChangeLog --diffTypes="data"
```

but it generates changelog file without any inserts, the same as without diffTypes.

Properties:

```
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
classpath=postgresql.jdbc.jar 
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/knightsaga
username=postgres
password=postgres
# default changelog to use, relative to classpath
changeLogFile=./changelogs/db.changelog.xml
### DIFF params ###
referenceUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/knightsaga
referenceUsername=postgres
referencePassword=postgres
```

How to include data there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to run generateChangelog command without using properties file? You can specify all of the parameters in the command line like in following example :

> liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath=postgresql.jdbc.jar --changeLogFile=./changelogs/db.changelog.xml --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/knightsaga" --username=postgres --password=postgres --diffTypes="data" generateChangeLog

Comment: I'll check it. Anyway I've learnd that liquibase can't migrate data (diff doesn't support diffTypes=data) so I'm not going to use diffTypes...

Comment: is that a known bug that diffTypes=data isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

In your properties file, your target and source databases are the same. If you do a comparison / diff of the same database against the same database there would be no differences to detect or script.

Look specifically at the lines I've marked with `>>>`

```
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
classpath=postgresql.jdbc.jar 
>>>  url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/knightsaga
username=postgres
password=postgres
# default changelog to use, relative to classpath
changeLogFile=./changelogs/db.changelog.xml
### DIFF params ###
>>>  referenceUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/knightsaga
referenceUsername=postgres
referencePassword=postgres
```